# How do I remove a folder, but keep all subfodlers and files, only in one git branch?

Tags: git, github, directory, mv, rm

I am setting up a git branch that needs to have a different directory structure to the rest of them. The files are all the same, however, they must essentially all be moved a level up. There are a lot of files, and I do not know how to move them alltogether using git.

Currently, it looks somehting like this:

```
Root Directory
    |
    - Main Folder
    |    |
    |     - Sub Folder 1 with a lot of subfolders and files
    |    |
    |     - Sub Folder 2 with a lot of other subfodlers and files
    |
    - A couple of random files
```

What I want to end up with:

```
Root Directory
    |
    - Sub Folder 1 with a lot of subfolders and files
    |
    - Sub Folder 2 with a lot of other subfodlers and files
    |
    - A couple of random files
```

However, this change should be exclusively in one branch.

How would I do that?

Comment: Is the branch to be ultimately remerged into main branch at some later point, or is it intended to be distinct for good?

Comment: It is intended to be distinct, and will never be merged into the main branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few useful background things to know here before you start:

- Git only stores *files*, not folders.
- Every Git commit stores a *complete snapshot* of *all* of your files—or rather, all of your *committed* files.  This is where what Git calls *untracked files* come in.
- The snapshots are made from files that are stored what Git calls, variously, your *index* or your *staging area*.  (It has one more old name, which is now supposed to be used for something else, but sometimes some things will refer to the *cache*.  All three names are about the same thing.)

Git stores these files in *commits*.  Git is really all about commits.  Each commit is numbered—but not in a nice easy sequential "commit #1, commit #2, ..." fashion.  Instead, each commit gets a unique *hash ID*, with the hash IDs appearing completely random and unrelated to previous commits.  These hash IDs are the big ugly strings of letters-and-numbers like [`83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6) that `git log` spits out.

Since *every* file is in *every* commit, it's important for Git to save them in a way that doesn't use up your entire disk drive right away.  So the saved files are compressed and, further, *shared* across different commits.  Git can do this because it uses a special, Git-only, freeze-dried format to store the files.  Files in this form *cannot be changed*, but can be shared.  This means that *no existing commit can be changed*.  **Every** commit in your repository is archived, more or less permanently.<sup>1</sup>  Think of commits as permanent (they *mostly* are) and unchangeable.  They *are* the history, stored in the repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's possible to remove commits, but it's a bit hard and Git generally doesn't do it right away either—so even if you *think* a commit is gone, and can't find it right away, it's probably still in there.

---

#### Getting work done

Now, this is all well and good for archiving, but these read-only freeze-dried files are completely useless for actually getting any actual *work* done.  For that, Git provides what Git calls a *work-tree*.  That's simply the place where you do your work.

Into the work-tree, Git extracts the freeze-dried files from some commit, rehydrating them so that they have their normal everyday form.  You can now see and work with these files.  You simply pick one commit—usually, the *last* commit on some *branch*—and say: *Get me that commit*, and Git does that.  It finds the frozen commit and enumerates all the files in it:

- `main-folder/sub1/file1`: *Aha*, says Git, *this work-tree has no `main-folder`, let's make one.  And it has no `sub1` in the `main-folder` I just made, let's make that too.  Now I can create new file `main-folder/sub1/file1`.*
- `main-folder/sub1/file2`: *Hey*, says Git, *there's already a main-folder/sub1, I can just create new file `file2` in there.*

This process repeats as needed: Git has *files*, as listed in the commit, that it has to reconstitute.  When it's done with that, if the work-tree *was* empty when you started, well, now it has the rehydrated version of every file from that commit.  No *folders* were stored, but there was no need to store them.

If you now switch from *that* commit to a different commit, Git will *remove* all the files it created just for that commit, and replace them with files for the other, different commit.  If it removes *all* the files from `main-folder/sub1`, it also removes the directory `main-folder/sub1`.  If it winds up removing everything in `main-folder`, it removes that too.  Then it goes about extracting all the files from the commit you want now, *creating* any directories/folders as required.

In fact, Git interleaves all of this work, creating and deleting, and optimizing: if you switch from commit `a123456...` to commit `b789abc...`, and 99% of the files in the two commits are *the same*, well, there's no need to go mucking with them in the work-tree after all, is there?  And, with this particular form of `git checkout`, Git adds a safety check before switching commits: *For each file I have to remove or replace, is the file in the work-tree "clean"?*  If the file is "clean", it's safe to remove or replace it.  If it's "dirty"—if you've changed it since Git extracted it, and you might want to keep your changes that switching would clobber—Git will warn you about this and, by default, refuse to switch commits.

#### The index / staging-area

There is one huge honking wrinkle in this process.  Reading through the above, you'd think: *Okay, we have commits with freeze-dried files, and the work-tree with normal files.*  But there's a third entity that Git puts *between* these two.  This is the index / staging-area.

Like the commits themselves, the index is mostly invisible.  It's actually just a plain file, `.git/index` in most cases—this gets more complicated eventually, but it starts out as just this plain file.  What's in the file is, in essence, a copy of the commit you extracted–all the freeze-dried files, using only a hash ID (like commit hash IDs) to identify them.  Unlike the actual frozen files in commits, though, the copies that are in the index *can* be changed.<sup>2</sup>

This is what `git add` does: it freeze-dries the file and sticks *that* version in the index.  If the file *wasn't* in the index before, well, now it is.  If it *was* in the index before, this kicks out the previous version.  **In either case, the new freeze-dried file is ready to be committed.**  When you run `git commit`, Git just packages up all the ready-to-go files from the index, into the new commit.  That's *why* `git commit` is so fast: it really has very little work left to do.

The files that are in the index aren't stored in folders at all.  There's just one giant list: file `path/to/file1` has *these* freeze-dried contents, file `path/to/file2` has *these other* freeze-dried contents, and so on.  But one way or another, the presence of the file *in* the index—along with the freeze-dried ready-to-commit content—are what make the rehydrated file in the work-tree *tracked*.  A *tracked* file is one that is in the index, so **an *untracked* file is simply any file that is in the work-tree, but not in the index.**  Since `git commit` archives what's in the *index*, not what's in the work-tree, only *tracked* files get committed.

---

<sup>2</sup>The tricky part here is that putting a new file into the index actually freeze-dries the file and stores it in the *repository*, creating a new hash ID if the new contents are truly new, or sharing some existing hash ID if the freeze-dried contents match any existing file.  Now that the supposedly-new file has been reduced to just a hash ID, it fits in the same slot in the index that the old file occupied!

---

#### With that out of the way, the answer is now easy

To make a new commit that, in that commit, stores *only* certain files, just set things up so that your *index* has just those files in it.  To do that, *remove* all the totally-unwanted files from your index, which will also remove the work-tree copies:

```
git rm ...
```

Since the index stores them by their *path relative to the top of the work-tree*, you'll want to save all the files you want to keep somewhere.  The easiest way to do that is to *rename* them in both the work-tree *and* the index:

```
git mv main-folder/sub1 sub1
```

which will create (by renaming, in this case) the `sub1` folder in your work-tree if needed, then rename all the *tracked* files in the index—remember that `git mv` has to work with the index as well as the work-tree—from their `main-folder/sub1/file1` etc paths to have `sub1/file1` etc paths.  The `git mv` command, like the `git rm` command, then drags the work-tree files along with it.

(Conveniently, or maybe not sometimes, when `git mv` renames the folder in-place, that also renames any *untracked* files within it.  Since the rest of Git isn't really interested in untracked files, a later `git checkout` won't move them back!)

Since, underneath everything, Git stores files by content—using the hash IDs of the freeze-dried files—all of this renaming is mostly free.  Git needs a little bit of space to store the updated *names*—commits have to store the full names along with the hash IDs, and the *names* can't easily be shared here as they're different<sup>3</sup>—but the actual contents are shared with the files that have different names in other commits.

Note that when you switch back and forth between this commit, with these `sub1/file1` type names, to any commit that has the `main-folder/sub1/file1` type names, Git may well have to churn hard on your work-tree, removing all the `sub1/file1` names first, then creating new, empty `main-folder` and `main-folder/sub1` directories to hold the (in the end same!) files that used to be in `sub1/file1` and so on.  When and if Git can be clever enough to realize that it could just *rename* those files in the work-tree, Git might do that, but the easy dumb way, which is what Git usually starts with, is just to remove and re-create them.  This will show up in the OS-level file time-stamps: if Git removes a file and re-creates it, it gets "now" as its on-disk work-tree-file time-stamp.

---

<sup>3</sup>Inside commits—but not in the index—Git goes right back to a tree-structured naming scheme.  So if `sub1` in the top level of this new commit is 100% identical to the `sub1` that was in `main-folder/sub1` of some other commit, Git will actually share the underlying *tree* object for the `sub1` sub-tree of the root tree of the new commit.  The root tree will of course be different as it will name `sub1` as one of its sub-trees, and not name `main-folder` as one of its sub-trees.  But all of this is mere implementation detail: none of it shows up in the index and work-tree.

Answer (score 0):

the folder structure is specific to each branch. So first you need to check out the the new branch

git checkout branch1
then move subfolder 1 and 2 out of main folder
delete
git commit

if you have any further questions on how git works there are many great tutorials = maybe starting with https://girliemac.com/blog/2017/12/26/git-purr/ GIT with kittens

Comment: I know those basics (cute tutorial though thank you), and I am checkout in the branch. What I don't know is how to actually _move_ the subfolders  When you say move, do you mean actually `cd` to the folder and `move`? I would have thought that would permanently move those files in windows, rather than exclusively in git, but i may be mistaken.

Comment: yes, just like that. GIT keeps track of it for you and changes the actual windows folder according to the branch you check out.